# return a model with .Include to view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following item model:

```
public class Item

 {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
   public virtual Comment Comment {get; set;}
 }
```

I have the following User model:

```
public class User

 {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string UserName {get; set;}
   public string email {get; set;}
 }
```

And I have the following Comment model:

```
public class Comment

 {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string text {get; set;}
   public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}

   public int ItemId {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
   public virtual Item Item {get; set;}

   public int UserId {get; set;}
   [ForeignKey("UserId")]
   public virtual User User {get; set;}
 }
```

In my onModelCreating Context I have

```
 modelBuilder.Enitity<Item>().HasOptional(c=>c.Comment).WithMany();
```

My aim is to return to a view the items which only the requesting user has commented on.

So far I have done:

```
 int UserId = db.Users.Where(u=>u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name))
 .Select(u=>u.Id).FirstOrDefault();


 var itemsWithComments = db.Items.Include(c=>c.Comments).......
```

At this point I want to be able to say: Select the items which the UserId == Comments.UserId, return the Items as a list.

And my View (using Razor)

```
 @model IEnumerable <project.Models,Item>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 .....
 .....
```

Any help is much appreciated.

If you need me to clarify any point(s) please ask.

Kind regards

Comment: you mean `.Where(c=> c.UserId == UserId)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to filter only the comments from a specific user, you can't use `Include()` but you can use a projection to select a filtered list.

```
var itemsWithComments = db.Items.Select(o => new
{
    Item = o,
    Comments = o.Comments.Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
});
```

If the user is attached to the item itself then the query is simple:

```
var itemsWithComments = db.Items.Include(o => o.Comments).Where(o => o.UserId == userId);
```

One thing to remember - calling `Select()` will almost always reset any `Include()` calls before it so `query.Include().Select()` will not have the include while `query.Select().Include()` will.

Comment: Hello Knaģis, I am wanting the results filtered. I'm unsure as to how to return the results to the user. I receive "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Infrastructure.DbQuery '1 [<>f_AnonymousType5'2'.....dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable '1[project.Models.Comment]". Thank you for your help